# advanced IF in dax

Tags: powerbi, dax

i need to change my origional "Total Budget Amount" to include different formulas in the new "TotalBudgetTest" when conditions is meet. the conditions is when art=220 it should return 15%*totalBudgettest from art 101 + Total budget amount from art 220. this would mean that it is 15 * 1.321.049+ 1.878.566 my problem is that my code right now dont add the 15% ontop of the value(1.878.566) when conditions is not meet it should return the values from total budget amount

the goal is to make the measure like in the picture
[image]

my code so fare is

```
TotalBudgetTest =
VAR _if =
    IF (
        HASONEVALUE ( Art[Art Code] ),
        SWITCH (
            VALUES ( Art[Art Code] ),
            101, [Project Cost Amount],
            220, [Total Budget Amount],
            [Total Budget Amount]
        )
    )
RETURN
    _if
```

can anybody help my?

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the context for `[Total Budget Amount]` when the ArtCode is 220. You have to change that row in the SWITCH-statement to something like this:

```
HASONEVALUE( Art[Art Code] ),
    SWITCH (
        VALUES ( Art[Art Code] ),
        101, [Project Cost Amount],
        220, [Total Budget Amount] + 
             CALCULATE(
                 [Project Cost Amount], 
                 [Art Code] = 101
             )*0,15),
        [Total Budget Amount]
    )
```

I havent tried this solution (I usually do befor posting) so let me know i it doesn't work and I'll have a second look. Besids, I don't understand the logic/reasoning behind your code, so I probably have misunderstood what you're trying to calculate.

Edit 1:

I made up a data set and I tried this code:

```
_if = 
 var _if = 
IF( 
    HASONEVALUE('Data'[Leve4]);
    SWITCH(
        VALUES(Data[Leve4]);
        101; [Project Cost Amount]*0,1;
        220; [Project Cost Amount]+CALCULATE([Project Cost Amount]; Data[Leve4] = 101)*0,1;
        [Project Cost Amount]
    )
)

return 
_if
```

When adding it to a small data set table I get this result. As you can see the calculat can be evaluated even inside a switch statement.

[image]

Comment: HI ::) thx for your answer. your code have the same probelm as mine. because of the switch function it only return one value which means we cant use + calculate() this means that we dont add 15%* 1.321.049+ 1.878.566. the logic behind the code should be when art code = 100 then the result is 15%* 1.321.049+ 1.878.566 and when art code != 220 when return [total budget amount]

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "cant use + Calculate()" since you haven't provided what your data model looks like. I did a small test and it works for me. I'll update my answer and include what I did shortly.

Comment: i mean in switch the argument result cant return a result that is adding two values together. it must be a scalar value. and one more thing. have you nog forgot the if statment in your code? i cant run your code without the if in the begining.

Comment: Ok, the first code, the one starting with HASONEVALUE (in my answer) was just an excerpt of your code sorry if I was not clear. I didn't add all the stuff around the Switch (the var, the if, the return etc) since only the SWITCH-code was of interest, my bad. 
Also, I don't understand your "can't return a result that is adding two values together, it must be a scalar value" as you can see in the image of the table I added row 4 is 10 000 + 900 which is what the switch statement evaluates when Level4 = 220 (In my example)

Comment: i agree with U after my own test, but in my model it only return one of the two value. my data model is as follows (simplified) the are 3 tabels. the art, project budget and project cost. the art is a dimension and the others are fact tabels. both fact tabels are connect to the dimension but there are no direct connection between the two fact tabels but because they both are connect to the dimension they are indirect connected. maybe i can use the related function to activate the relation between the two tabels?

Comment: i can create the connection with crossfilter, but now it filters on 220 and not 101. can i make a filter so that i change the filter of 220 to 101 but still return the result in the 220 row? SWITCH (
        VALUES (Art[Art Code]),
        101, [Project Cost Amount],
        220, [Total Budget Amount] + 
             CALCULATE(
                 [Project Cost Amount], 
                 CROSSFILTER('Project Budgets'[SFK_Art],Art[SK_Art],Both)
             )*0.15),
        [Total Budget Amount]
    )

Comment: I think it would be easier if we connect via email to sort this out. would that be ok for you?

Comment: totally. maybe with microsoft teams which gives the opputunity with screen sharing?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225360/discussion-between-oscarlar-and-mathies-skov-jeppesen).